# Why is git checkout named like that?

Tags: git

From what I understand, `git checkout` changes the state of files in the current directory to what it was at a specific point in the tree. Hence it can be used to switch branches or to visit a previous commit.

Why was the name `checkout` chosen for this operation?

Is the analogy to "I'm going to go check this out"?
Is it to checking out books from the library?

I'm not asking whether the name is a good idea or not, or trying to offer judgement on that myself -- I'm just wondering what the historical origin of the name is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Much of this is historical.  Pre-git version control systems (VCSes) used the verbs *check in* and *check out* as well.

An excerpt from a book I'm working on:

> Used as a verb,
>   *to version* means
>   *to put under control of the VCS*.
>   Used as a noun, *version* means
>   *a specific version taken from the VCS*
>   (of one file, or of a group of files).
>   Usually the noun form appears with additional modifiers,
>   as in the phrase *the old version of `kanga.c`*
>   or *version 2.1 of `roo.c`*.
>   If no specific files are listed, we typically mean everything,
>   or at least everything recently under discussion:
>   *version 2.1* (of everything in the repository,
>   or of the specific files and/or directories we were talking about).
>   The word *revision* is always a noun,
>   but otherwise means the same thing as *version*.
>
> Another verb, *to check in*,
>   means *to store into the VCS*.
>   As you might expect, if we can *check in*,
>   we can also *check out*,
>   meaning *extract from the VCS*.
>   Some VCSes add the verb *to update*,
>   which they may use to distinguish between
>   extracting an older version (which you *check out*)
>   and moving up to the latest and (we hope) greatest
>   (to which you *update*).
>   Mercurial uses *update*
>   as a pure synonym for *checkout*.

Comment: Is there a way to be notified when your book is released?

Comment: @Alok-- Not really ... it's currently stalled a bit because my examples are not going well and I have a real job again (I started on it while between gigs).

Answer (score 5):

I assume the one who can tell you where the name came from Is ***`Linus Torvalds`*** who developed git.

Based up on the action which checkout does - switching the content of the working directory i can only assume that the origin of this word is like what you have described

***`Checking out book from the library`***

From the documentation:
**https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html**

> ***`git-checkout`*** - **Checkout** a branch or paths **to the working tree**

---

## ***`Links:`***

- Pack files: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles
- Checkout: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html

Comment: Checkout doesn't *necessarily* get content from pack files.  Content is stored as "loose objects" until packed.  A new clone generally has just one pack file, but once you've done a bunch of work, it is a mixture of loose and packed objects.

Comment: I completely agree with you. If nothing is packed it will not grab it form the .pack file. I usually pack my repo every single day using `git gc --aggressive`. This is why i thing on it this way.

Answer (score 5):

It's part of the [common vocab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control#Common_vocabulary) of versioning systems, and although its behaviour is different from the first, lock based, versioning systems, it seems like a natural evolution.

2005

```
 man git checkout
```

> NAME
>          git-checkout - Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree
>   [...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or
>          the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also
>          update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.

---

2000

```
 svn help checkout
```

> ```
> checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
> ```

---

1986

```
 man cvs
```

> ```
> checkout
>    Check out sources for editing
> [...]
>
>          Create or update a working directory containing copies of the  source
>          files  specified  by modules.  You must execute checkout before using
>          most of the other cvs commands, since most of them  operate  on  your
>          working directory.
>
>          The  modules  are either symbolic names for some collection of source
>          directories and files, or paths to directories or files in the repos‐
>          itory.  The symbolic names are defined in the modules file.  See node
>          'modules' in the CVS manual.
>
>          Depending on the modules you specify, checkout may recursively create
>          directories and populate them with the appropriate source files.  You
>          can then edit these source files at any time (regardless  of  whether
>          other  software  developers  are  editing  their  own  copies  of the
>          sources); update them to include new changes applied by others to the
>          source  repository;  or commit your work as a permanent change to the
>          source repository.
> ```

---

1982 RCS

```
man co
```

> co retrieves a revision from each RCS file and stores it into the corresponding working file.
>
> Pathnames matching an RCS suffix denote RCS files; all others denote working files. Names are paired as explained in ci(1).
>
> Revisions of an RCS file can be checked out locked or unlocked. Locking a revision prevents overlapping updates. A revision checked out for reading or processing (e.g., compiling) need not be locked. A revision checked out for editing and later checkin must normally be locked. Checkout with locking fails if the revision to be checked out is currently locked by another user. (A lock can be broken with rcs(1).) Checkout with locking also requires the caller to be on the access list of the RCS file, unless he is the owner of the file or the superuser, or the access list is empty. Checkout without locking is not subject to accesslist restrictions, and is not affected by the presence of locks.

---

1972

SCCS didn't have a checkout, it had a check. <s>Maybe somebody can confirm if it cvs took the idea from there.</s>

```
man SCCS
```

> check  Like info except that nothing is printed if nothing is being edited, and a non-zero exit status is returned if anything is being edited. The intent is to have this included in an ''install'' entry in a makefile to insure that everything is included into the SCCS file before a version is installed.

Comment: SCCS uses the verb *get* rather than *checkout*.  CVS's verbs are the same as RCS's.

Comment: CVS also allows `cvs get` as a synonym for `cvs checkout`. I guess `git get` wasn't included because it looks weird.

Comment: I should add, SCCS (which is still actively developed!) separates extraction into *get* (read-only) and *edit* (equivalent of RCS `co -l`).